# Insert data based on sequence number

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following data in a table:

```
Index   Domain  Name
-------------------------
1       AAA     Aaron.B
NULL    NULL    NULL
1       AAA     Aaron.B2
NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL
2       AAA2    Aaron.D
NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL
```

What I would like to achieve is the following:

```
Index   Domain  Name
------------------------------
1      AAA      Aaron.B
1      AAA      Aaron.B
1      AAA      Aaron.B2
1      AAA      Aaron.B2
1      AAA      Aaron.B2
1      AAA      Aaron.B2
1      AAA      Aaron.B2
1      AAA      Aaron.B2
1      AAA      Aaron.B2
2      AAA2     Aaron.D
2      AAA2     Aaron.D
2      AAA2     Aaron.D
2      AAA2     Aaron.D
```

Any assistance and offered explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,
John

Comment: Impossible -- if you don't have another column, that defines the order of the rows, there's no reliable way to determine which values such a `NULL, NULL, NULL` tuple should be filled with.

Comment: Thnx Marc, I tried using row_number() route but quickly found I didn't have sufficient TSQL skills to progress. Damn!

Comment: To expand a little on what @stickybit wrote - tables in a relational database are unsorted by nature. There's no inherent row order that you can use. This means you can't know how many times to repeat any of the data rows.

Comment: @johnm, add an `IDENTITY` column to your table. This will add an increasing number to each new row. Thus it is easy to use your data in the *order it was inserted*. Otherwise you are out of luck. The result will be random... Very important: With small sets it is very likely to work as expected. Such things tend to pass all tests and break in production with hardly to find errors...

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will do:

```
declare @t table ([index] int, domain nvarchar(max), [name] nvarchar(max))

insert @t values
    (1   ,    'AAA' ,    'Aaron.B'  ),
    (NULL,    NULL,    NULL     ),
    (1   ,    'AAA' ,    'Aaron.B2' ),
    (NULL,    NULL,    NULL     ),
    (NULL,    NULL,    NULL     ),
    (NULL,    NULL,    NULL     ),
    (NULL,    NULL,    NULL     ),
    (NULL,    NULL,    NULL     ),
    (NULL,    NULL,    NULL     ),
    (2   ,    'AAA2',    'Aaron.D'  ),
    (NULL,    NULL,    NULL     ),
    (NULL,    NULL,    NULL     ),
    (NULL,    NULL,    NULL     )


; with t as
(
    select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by (select null)) rn
    from @t t1
)
select isnull(x.[index], t.[index])
    , isnull(x.domain, t.domain)
    , isnull(x.[name], t.[name])
from
(
    select *
        ,  (select max(t2.rn) from t t2 where t2.[index] is not null and t1.rn > t2.rn) rn2
    from t t1
)x
left join t on x.rn2 = t.rn
```

Result:

```
----------- ------------ -------------
1           AAA          Aaron.B
1           AAA          Aaron.B
1           AAA          Aaron.B2
1           AAA          Aaron.B2
1           AAA          Aaron.B2
1           AAA          Aaron.B2
1           AAA          Aaron.B2
1           AAA          Aaron.B2
1           AAA          Aaron.B2
2           AAA2         Aaron.D
2           AAA2         Aaron.D
2           AAA2         Aaron.D
2           AAA2         Aaron.D
```

Comment: Hi Kirill, Thnx for your response and time to look at my problem. I will most certainly test it out as soon as I'm back into the office. Reds, John

Comment: This answer is wrong. There's no guarantee of how the numbers will be ordered, since `order by (select null)` will return an arbitrary order.